# Drupal 7: Localhost/user link defaults to website/user

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I am really new to Drupal and playing around with this existing Drupal site.

I did a FTP transfer of all the files to my local computer directory. I currently got it on a Vagrant box and I can access the site via `http://192.168.56.101/html`.

I can do `http://192.168.56.101/html/anything-but-user` and it brings me to the proper area on the site. However I can't do `localhost/html/user`, because it redirects me to the website URL rather than the local URL.

I tried clearing the cache (with Drush). I scanned all files in the system and changed the web url to the local URL [not sure if I need to do any other command], and I can't seem to find anything in the `.htaccess` files that would lead me to this.

The `href="/user` I would greatly appreciate any advice or help in figuring out this solution.

--UPDATED

There was a module called "Secure Pages" that was causing the user and registration links to be locked and static to prevent redirects to phishing sites. I had to disable this module using "drush pm-disable securepages" in the terminal.

Comment: Can you list the enabled modules? I have the feeling that it could be something like [securelogin](https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin) that causes this behaviour..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some typical items you may want to check:

- Check if you get the same problem using another browser. If with another browser it works, then it is pretty sure a cookie problem. To solve that, delete the cookie in the browser where you have the problem.
- Make sure "clean urls" is enabled. Refer to "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165029/clean-url-leads-to-duplicate-url-after-migration-to-another-hosting/165044?s=1%7C3.9647#165044" for more details on that.
- Make sure the value of "base_url" is set correctly (in your [settings.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=7.x#n248)).
- If module [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) is enabled, then try to (at least temporary) disable that moduel to see if it helps.

Comment: If he can access any other part of the site, it couldn't be clean urls. base_url would also be set correctly in that case. I would possibly check Secure Login as well as Secure Pages. Those two are typically used together so that you can be logged in on both protocols.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, there was a mod called "SecurePages" that was causing the URLs to be static to prevent someone from changing them and redirecting users to a phishing site.

Comment: Oh, didn't see you'd answered your own question. Can you update your original question?